# Kibana 4 Ready-Made Dashboard?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I'm feeding log data from eight apache hosts into Elasticsearch, then using Kibana 4 to show the end users graphs, totals, and so on.

I see examples on the net where *others* have designed some very nifty visualizations and dashboards.  Is there a repository where one can grab the json and import?

Answer (score 1):

It is preferable to create your own visualizations due to following reasons:-

> 1. Everyone have different input data
> 2. Easy to create visualization
> 3. Simple to visualize as per requirement
> 4. Easy to learn & implement
> 5. No requirement of coding :P

& much more......

Answer (score 0):

It would not be possible to use dashboards and visuals from other users as the visuals and dashboards are linked to the search queries which most surely will not be same for different users. I suggest that you think of what you can visualize using your specific data and then implement the visuals in Kibana. I dont find kibana to be very different from other BI tools around so it should be fairly easy.
Be happy to discuss further.